# How can I search all mail from a specific user or email address in Outlook 2013?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

If I type something in the search field above the emails list, it searches all the email fields (from, to, cc, subject, even content), but I have thousands of emails so it will still take forever to find the email I'm looking for.

How can I find all emails sent by a specific email address.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a rule that put all the emails of this specific email sender in a new folder and then search in it.
 [Rules in Outlook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-HA102749402.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I thought of that, but I have about a dozen folders and I don't want to remove the mails from them. AFAIK, filters only move emails, they don't also copy them.

Comment: Is your Indexing Options enabled ?